# Patch for Suhosin for PHP 5.4.15

Tags: patch-management, php

I want to test if the [latest dev-Suhosin Version](https://github.com/stefanesser/suhosin) for PHP 5.4.15 is stable and now I want to compile it along with PHP.

According to [this](http://brandonwamboldt.ca/compiling-php-with-suhosin-83/) instructions (not the latest PHP and Suhosin but installation process should be the same) I have to patch a Suhosin Patch, but I can't find such a Patch? Do you know where I can find it, or how I could compile PHP (5.4.15) with Suhosin in another way?

Answer (score 2):

[Debian abandoned Suhosin](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=657698) for PHP 5.4. If you look through the [issues](https://github.com/stefanesser/suhosin/issues/17) on github the patch does not seem to work out of the box. I've tried patching some versions ago and had a lot of errors while running it in production.

So for now I'd refrain from using the patch with PHP 5.4. If you really want to try it you probably have to apply the various patches spread across the github issues (I only remember something `mb_*` related failed. I'd also do extensive testing before using it in production.

Comment: now i could compile php 5.4.15 with the suhosin dev-version stated above (without errors). but now i don't know how to test the build :) maybe i will wait for the next months until a new version of suhosin is in the wild.